# VideoView getDrawingCache is returning black

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot, android-videoview

So I'm trying to do a screen shot of a VideoView. I figured the easiest way would be:

```
videoView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Then when I need to take a screenshot:

```
Bitmap screenshot = videoView.getDrawingCache();
```

But for some reason the bitmap I get back is just black every time. Anyone had any success with this? I also tried:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(videoView.getWidth(), videoView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
videoView.draw(canvas);
```

But once again, this returns me a black image. I can see that the VideoView is hardly even documented in the Android javadocs. Any help?

Comment: This reminds me of the old days when I used to try and take screenshots of videos in WMP with Print screen and paint. I believe it is an issue where the surface view is just a transparent layer in the window and so cannot be snapshotted like you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the docs for [View#setDrawingCacheEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29):

> Enabling the drawing cache is similar
>   to setting a layer when hardware
>   acceleration is turned off. When
>   hardware acceleration is turned on,
>   enabling the drawing cache has no
>   effect on rendering because the system
>   uses a different mechanism for
>   acceleration which ignores the flag.
>   If you want to use a Bitmap for the
>   view, even when hardware acceleration
>   is enabled, see setLayerType(int,
>   android.graphics.Paint) for
>   information on how to enable software
>   and hardware layers.

It's possible that the VideoView operates with hardware acceleration and is bypassing the caching mechanism. A good source dive might shed some light.

**Edit** - [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-platform/xHIActZZ9PA) seems to clear some things up:

> Sorry, by its nature a SurfaceView does
>   not draw in the normal view hierarchy
>   update system, so it won't be drawn in
>   that.

(VideoView is a child of SurfaceView)

Comment: Hm. I can see that a view has setLayerType in the javadocs, but my VideoView doesn't have a setLayerType nor does View show me the constants it uses (To set it to View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE). This is such a weird class. It also says in the javadocs that there is a resume() method for VideoView, but mine doesn't show one of those? I'll keep looking around and possibly dive into the source.

Comment: You should probably think of SurfaceView as hardware magic. Your code apparently won't be able to touch the bits as they move to the screen.

Comment: Yeah I'm realizing that. So basically. I can't take a screenshot from a VideoView?

Comment: I don't think you can, unfortunately.

Comment: SurfaceView is a "hole" inside the window, it therefore cannot be cached inside a bitmap. We are aware of this limitation and we'd like to get something better but there's nothing planned for now.

Comment: did any one try http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-and-save-a-screenshot-from-a-surfaceview,880.html , here there are showing capture bitmap using surface view.

Comment: @RomainGuy So what is the alternative way ? I am not directly using SurfaceView, but my webview has a html5 video player and not able to capture the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Since API 10, you can use [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) to retrieve a frame at given time (in **micro seconds**). Here is a sample code:

```
public Bitmap videoFrame(String uri, long msec) {       
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {                       
        retriever.setDataSource(uri);            
        return retriever.getFrameAtTime(msec);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I haven't revisited this in a long time, but this is good to know, thank you. However, this wouldn't have helped in my instance as much of what I was wanting to screenshot was streaming video.

Comment: @Arbi thanks, i was able to do this with a video stored locally on the phone. However, when the video is streamed in the VideoView, I can't seem to capture the video frame. Do you know how?

Comment: you need the get the uri of the streamed video

Comment: Hi @Arbi . I placed a sample "http://www.test.com/myVideo.mp4" into the uri parameter but it is not successful. It seems that the function videoFrame() above only works if the video is downloaded on the device

Comment: You're not providing the protocol (I wonder if you were able to play the video). Try with something like `new URL("you_full_url").toExternalForm()` to be sure you're giving a correct url otherwise you'll see an exception.

Comment: At this point in time (03/01/2017), the above code worked with an external (http) uri as long as I used [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)](this setDataSource call)