# Get view's Bitmap when Hardware acceleration is on

Tags: android, android-layout, hardware-acceleration

I have a question about the hardware acceleration in Android 4.0
I want to get a view's bitmap. It's working if the hardware acceleration is disabled but when it is enabled nothing is displayed on the screen.
I use this code to capture the view's bitmap.

```
item.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = item.getDrawingCache();
```

Does anybody have any idea why this is not working with hardware acceleration enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem in the Android Rendering System: [VideoView getDrawingCache is returning black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278707/videoview-getdrawingcache-is-returning-black#comment5950460_5278927) - won't be fixed soonish.