# getDrawingCache() always returns null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-view, android-notifications

I know this question has been asked quite often, but this seems to be different. I've tried 6 solutions from StackOverflow and it didn't work. I'm trying to put the drawing someone made into a `Notification.BigPictureStyle` when they leave the app.

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        _thread.setRunning(true);
        _thread.start();            
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        _thread.setRunning(false);

        measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        layout(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

        buildDrawingCache(false);
        Bitmap currentState = Bitmap.createBitmap(getDrawingCache());
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(DrawActivity.this, DrawActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(DrawActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        Notification noti = new Notification.BigPictureStyle(
                new Notification.Builder(DrawActivity.this)
                    .setContentTitle("Your drawing")
                    .setContentText("Unfold to see drawing")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent))
        .setSummaryText("Here you can see how you left your drawing.")
        .bigPicture(currentState)
        .build();

        manager.notify(1023, noti);

    }
}
```

But I always get a `NullPointerException` at this line:

```
Bitmap currentState = Bitmap.createBitmap(getDrawingCache());
```

This code is from StackOverflow with enabling all these caches. Can someone see what's wrong?

By the way, I'm using Android 4.1.1 of course.

Comment: Is hardware acceleration turned on? in which case setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); is ineffective. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29) You can also check that the drawing cache is enabled using isDrawingCacheEnabled() after your call to enable drawing cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278707/videoview-getdrawingcache-is-returning-black) more info [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/xHIActZZ9PA)...

Problem appears to be that you can't access contents of a surfaceview - apparently you can capture the contents of an ImageView... I assume your using a surfaceView and thus encountering the same problem... If your willing to dig further [this](http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-and-save-a-screenshot-from-a-surfaceview,880.html) might help (from one of the above threads/topics)

If your not using a surfaceview then setLayerType might be your answer...

Comment: What does your draw code look like for the surfaceView? perhaps draw the canvas to a bitmap? Let me know if your still stuck... Seeing your draw code (or some of it) would probably help...

Comment: I already gave up on it. Too many limitations for a SurfaceView. Looking for other approaches now.