# Record entire screen, including front camera preview

Tags: android, surfaceview, mediarecorder

I wrote a small game. It has a front facing cam preview implemented. I want to be able to record the entire screen to a mp4. How would I do that? Anyone know a nice tutorial for recording the entire screen to mp4 (in code, so not just screenshots.. I want to enable the user to make a recording, while playing the game).

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. AFAIK, you cannot read from a `SurfaceView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps aren't allowed to grab the screen contents (see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/9Li2jizwH2Y/M-4eNPzdBtIJ)).

> [L]etting applications grab the screen's content liberally is a serious security risk, which is why the platform prevents it (taking a snapshot requires either direct physical manipulation from the user, or using a debugging tool).

And as @CommonsWare mentioned in his comment you can't use the `getDrawingCache` method either to grab a `Bitmap` of the `View` if you're using a `SurfaceView` or one of its children (e.g. `VideoView`). More details about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278707/videoview-getdrawingcache-is-returning-black).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as @Michael stated, directly accessing the screenshot and framebuffer mechanisms is not possible.  That doesn't mean you're *completely* out of luck, though, if you want to record gaming sessions.  It's just more work.

If you generate a perfect record of the various actions in your game, save that record.  You can then build a service (web service, local, whatever) that accepts the record as an input.  In effect, it would replay the game.  You'd then reconstruct the game in such a manner that you could generate a video.

You could also replay in the Android emulator and create a video from that.  Not as easily deployable, but it depends on what you want to do with it.