# How to capture image accurately from a video view in android

Tags: android, android-videoview, video-capture

I am making an app where the video is captured using the code:

```
Bitmap bmframe =mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(currentPosition*1000);
```

but is not capturing accurately.Its capturing few microseconds before the current position.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: Did you get any solutions? I am getting same issues

Answer (score -1):

Try this

put the below within a method

```
yourvideoView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
yourvideoView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = yourvideoView.getDrawingCache();
// save the bitmap or do what ever
```

Call the method after your required timing using a `handler` or take image on a button click as you needed

Comment: But there is no work of DrawingCacheEnabled.I just need to capture the frame accurately.

Comment: It is to capture the screenshot of the videoview

Comment: I think theres a issue with that , you need to specify the layertype in it see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278707/videoview-getdrawingcache-is-returning-black

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43739/discussion-between-priyanka-minhas-and-arju)