# android get screenshot of current videoview

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I've seen a lot of old questions about this, maybe now there are some solutions. 
I want to take a screenshot of the current frame of my videoview. Videoview shows a real-time video using a rtsp-stream.

I try to take bitmap, but it's always black

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getLayoutParams().width , v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

**EDIT :**
`MediaMetadataRetriever` does not work with stream url, maybe works with video-file.
Using lib at this [link](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) (it's a wrapper of `MediaMetadataRetriever` that enable **rtsp** protocol input) I can save a frame of video, but there is a delay of 10 secs respect real-time videoview because it must create a new connection with streaming server.

I not test  `ThumbnailUtils`, but in Api I read that input is only file-path

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762643/android-take-screen-shot-programatically

Comment: May hope [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278707/videoview-getdrawingcache-is-returning-black) answer would help.

Comment: Your video play from youtube ?

Comment: no, it isn't. It's a streaming server of an ip live camera

Comment: hi. were you able to find a solution for this? i seem to be getting black screenshots as well (only for streamed video). When the video is already on the device, the screenshot is OK.

Answer (score 11):

Use TextureView instead VideoView. TextureView  has getBitmap() method. Here is the usage of TextureView as videoView

```
public class TextureVideoActivity extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

private static final String FILE_NAME = "myVideo.mp4";
private static final String TAG = TextureVideoActivity.class.getName();

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private TextureView mPreview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_texture_video);

    mPreview = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    mPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

}

public Bitmap getBitmap(){
   return  mPreview.getBitmap();
}

public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
    Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

    try {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer
                .setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(FILE_NAME));
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

        // don't forget to call MediaPlayer.prepareAsync() method when you use constructor for
        // creating MediaPlayer
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        // Make sure we stop video and release resources when activity is destroyed.
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

}
}
```

[Playing video on TextureView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: do you have an example being able to take a screenshot of the video  with textureview?

Comment: in `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` method `mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface)`