# convert video view to bitmap android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-videoview

I am trying to convert a videoview into bitmap. Here's the code I have tried.But here the bitmap is always null. Can anyone please tell me why and what is the correct way to do so.

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    videoView = new CustomVideoView(this);

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getApplicationContext());
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    video_relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams videoRelativeLayout_param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    video_relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(videoRelativeLayout_param);

    videoView.requestFocus();
    video_relativeLayout.addView(videoView);


    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.kitkat));

    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();

mainLayout.addView(video_relativeLayout);

    mainLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mainLayout.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = mainLayout.getDrawingCache();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `TextureView` instead of `VideoView` since it has `getBitmap()` method.

More information [here (android get screenshot of current videoview)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26584360/4856711).

Comment: getBitmap() is still returning null.

Comment: Pls. share how you got ? I have requirement to convert videos to bitmap.