# Android VideoView Snapshot (from live stream)

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, h.264

I'm coding an app that plays a live video stream coming from a video server (h264) trough a VideoView widget.

I need to retrieve a snapshot of the video an save it as a bitmap image (in jpg, or png format).

I wrote the following code that seems to work (since it doesn't hang neither throw exceptions) but all I got is a black image:

```
final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoH264);

    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            videoView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            videoView.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bmp = videoView.getDrawingCache();

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            File file = new File(path, "snapshot.jpg");

            try 
            {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);                 

                fOut.flush();       
                fOut.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try 
            {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

I tried to initialize the DrawingCache feature in the onCreate event of the activity but the app keeps to behave the same way.

Comment: Sounds like you are getting exactly this problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278707/videoview-getdrawingcache-is-returning-black