# get click position on surfaceview and show dialog

Tags: android, pdf, surfaceview

i want to get click x and y from surfaceview and also show dialog on same activity.

click listener is not available for surfaceview.

i am using android pdfview library to show pdf document , and it is using surfaceview to view PDF page.

https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

also, when i try to get drawing cache of surface view, it returns black view.

```
     final AlertDialog.Builder addSing = new AlertDialog.Builder(PDFViewActivity.this);

       addSing.setTitle("Do you want to add Signature here ?");
       addSing.setCancelable(false);

       addSing.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
       });

       addSing.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
       });


    PDFViewActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



               addSing.show();



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ist Getting click on Surface View :

For getting click on surface view implement onTouchListener and GestureDetector :

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (mInputListener != null)
                mInputListener.onTouchDown(new Vector2(event.getX(), event
                        .getY()));
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mInputListener != null)
                mInputListener.onTouchMove(new Vector2(event.getX(), event
                        .getY()));
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (mInputListener != null)
                mInputListener
                        .onTouchUp(new Vector2(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private class GestureListener extends
            GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            if (mInputListener != null)
                mInputListener.onDoubleTap(new Vector2(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            if (mInputListener != null)
                mInputListener.onSingleTapConfirmed(new Vector2(e.getX(), e
                        .getY()));
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            if (mInputListener != null)
                mInputListener.onSingleTap(new Vector2(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
        }

    }
```

and for further information on same please see [this](https://github.com/chiragjain/SurfaceGameProject/blob/master/SurfaceGameTest/src/com/app/surfacegame/gameutils/GameSurfaceView.java).

IInd SurfaceView Drawing Cache: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5278927/2274724)

IIIrd Showing Dialog: I think your code will work fine for showing dialog.

> Sorry, by its nature a SurfaceView does not draw in the normal view
>   hierarchy update system, so it won't be drawn in that.