# Android RenderScript to blur video in VideoView

Tags: android, renderscript, android-videoview

I know that I can use RenderScript on Android to blur images, but does anybody know if I can apply the same to video views so that my complete video is gaussian blurred?

Answer (score 1):

VideoView, which extends SurfaceView, does not utilize the drawing cache due to being hardware accelerated. This means you won't be able to get stills. I was forced to scrap the design I had using the paused video still.

Check out: [VideoView getDrawingCache is returning black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278707/videoview-getdrawingcache-is-returning-black)

Edit: As I look into this more, there might be a way through https://github.com/google/grafika, but I haven't seen anyone verify it as a performant workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a thumbnail of the video in front of it. You can then, blur the image using this lib: https://github.com/jrvansuita/GaussianBlur