# Capture Screenshots on button click from Youtube Player Android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Is there any possible way to capture video frames on button click from Youtube Player? Or Youtube player does not allow this?

Below code gives image with black screen:

```
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
rootView.buildDrawingCache(true);          
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
rootView.getDrawingCache(true).compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
               fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.close();
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Do you want to capture it through coding or some other way will also do it ?

Comment: through coding on button click, Don't want to interrupt the user's video viewing experience.

Comment: I think you can not capture screen with youtube player.

Comment: Yeah, I am next to you. But wants to prove wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5278927/1367571), children of `SurfaceView` are typically hardware accelerated and thus do not use the standard view hierarchy system.

The YouTube SDK most likely uses this object to display the video, and that is why your code is not working.

Comment: Hi Dextor, appreciate your efforts to reply. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Not if you want to do it programmatically. There are workarounds, but they involve using `ADB`.