# Taking screenshot of videoview and other multiple view in one layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have created an application that creates random number of layouts at run time. I need to capture a screenshot of the screen/my application after some time (not fixed). I am successfully creating a bitmap of the screen using following code:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapOfRootView(View v){
    v = v.getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

But whenever VideoView(s) is involved I am getting a black screen for the area of VideoView(s).

Here is one of the screenshot with VideoView. 
[image]

I have found the solution. But it would work if there is only one layout being used. For this purpose I used the following code from [VideoView getDrawingCache is returning black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278707/videoview-getdrawingcache-is-returning-black)

```
public Bitmap videoFrame(String uri, long msec) {       
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {                       
        retriever.setDataSource(uri);            
        return retriever.getFrameAtTime(msec);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I know it is possible to take screenshot of VideoView using above code if only video is being displayed on the screen. But, in my application multiple views are visible (ImageView, WebView) at the same time. I am looking for a solution a generic which works with any time of view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(rootView, rootView.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), rootView.getChildAt(0).getWidth());

private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int height, int width) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```