# Why VideoView is black when taking screenshot of multiple views in Android through code?

Tags: android, view, android-videoview

In my Android application I have multiple views running at the same time: ImageView, VideoView and WebView. However when I take a screenshot through code, the VideoView is black, which is not the case when manually taking a screenshot using Android device.

Why is this so?

Code used:

```
 try {
        View view = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Result of screenshot:
[image: Example of screenshot]

Comment: `VideoView` does not use the drawing cache. The system screenshot mechanism does not use your code for making a screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VideoView getDrawingCache is returning black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278707/videoview-getdrawingcache-is-returning-black)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use TextureVideoView like this: https://github.com/sprylab/texturevideoview